# Django ModelForm not calling clean

Tags: python, django, eclipse

I am performing a basic **Django ModelForm** *create/validate/save* operation.  My custom clean methods are not being called when `is_valid()` is being called when running the code under the Eclipse debugger and I set a breakpoint after the form creation and the call to `is_valid()`.

I have traced through the **Django** base code numerous times and it appears that the error dictionary on the ModelForm class is never set to `None`, which triggers the validation.  I suspect that this is due to an interaction with the debugger accessing the `_errors` attribute of the **ModelForm** to display in the variables pane.

When I remove all breakpoints and let the code flow naturally, I can prove that the custom clean code is running by issuing print statements.

Is this a flaw in the **Django ModelForm** design, an **Eclipse** problem or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class TestModel1(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    field2 = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py:**

```
from order.models import TestModel1
from django.forms import ModelForm

class OrderTestForm(ModelForm):
    
    def clean_field1(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['field1']
    
    def clean_field2(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['field2']
    
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel1
```

**My test harness:**

```
from forms import OrderTestForm

row = {'field1': 'test value', 'field2': '4', }

ff = OrderTestForm(row)

#ff.full_clean()
if ff.is_valid():
    ff.save()
else:
    print ff.errors
```

Comment: Try: ff = OrderTestForm(data=row)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried that with no change. I should clarify the problem a little.  If I have an Eclipse breakpoint on the ModelForm creation and STEP and then resume, the breakpoints in the clean are not fired.  BUT any print statements in the cleans are printed after I take that first step.  That means, I believe, that when Eclipse tries to access the ModelForm object to read its attributes it fires the clean.  This is expected behavior according to the Django docs.  It creates a problem, though, as the is_valid() will not work properly.

Comment: Can you please post your full test case?

Comment: The full test case is the code above running under Django 1.4 with Eclipse (Helios) and PyDev.  I have run the experiment on both Mac and Windows with the same result.  I set a breakpoint on the instantiation of the OrderTestForm and a breakpoint on any of the clean methods in the form.  The first breakpoint fires and I "F6" or step, which takes me to the "is_valid()" IF statement.  I "F8" or resume and the breakpoint in the clean methods does not fire.  IF I remove the first breakpoint (at the creation of the ModelForm), the second breakpoint (in the clean method) WILL fire.

Comment: Hmm. I can't explain why the Eclipse debugger wouldn't go to the clean method when you continue if you have the first breakpoint enabled. If you write a unit test for your form, and it passes you should be good to go despite the debugger not working as expected.

Comment: I am convinced that the debugger accesses the "_error" attribute of the ModelForm which creates an empty ErrorDict on that attribute.  According the code and documentation, accessing the attribute fires the clean.  However, later when is_valid is invoked, it assumes that the _error is "None" to fire the clean methods.  If it is not None, the is_valid assumes that a clean was already run.  It's a weird problem.

Comment: I have having this exact problem as well in pycharm.  The `__str__` method on form returns self.as_table() which resets the form.  This essentially makes it impossible to debug complicated form/view interactions.  WTH.

Comment: This failure to call clean occurred to me with pycharm when I passed an instance of the object already created from objectinstance = Object.objects.create(**data) to the ObjectForm instead of the raw data. form =ObjectForm(instance = objectinstance). When I changed this to form = ObjectForm(data = objectdata). My clean method was called.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the "answer" which is sort of a non-answer.  The exact use case was receiving a CSV file from a customer.  After inspection of the customer's actual data file, the data fields were padded with spaces -- many spaces.  I trimmed the input and shoved that trimmed dictionary into the form and everything worked.  Still does not explain why eclipse choked on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to dig a little deeper and debug the framework.

There's probably a difference between regular forms and model forms which causes this not to work, but this hack (overriding `is_valid()` instead of `clean(...)`) worked for me:

```
def is_valid(self):
    #run whatever ModelForm validations you need
    return super(OrderTestForm, self).is_valid()
```

Comment: The problem is that you can't touch ` self.cleaned_data[]` in that method because it's not created yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def clean_field1(self):
        print('ENTER CLEAN FIELD1')
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        field1 = cleaned_data.get('field1')
        if len(field1) < 10:
            print('FIELD1 ERROR')
            raise forms.ValidationError("FIELD 1 Cannot Be Empty")

def clean_field2(self):
        print('ENTER CLEAN FIELD2')
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        field2 = cleaned_data.get('field2')
        if len(field2) < 10:
            print('FIELD2 ERROR')
            raise forms.ValidationError("FIELD 2 Cannot Be Empty")

def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        print('CLEAN')
        print(cleaned_data)
```

In my case i never put `cleaned_data = super().clean()` that's why it's never called. Also the `print()` help you to know which function called first

Answer (score -1):

What if you try:

```
from order.models import TestModel1
from django.forms import ModelForm

class OrderTestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel1

    def clean_field1(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['field1']
        print value 
        return value

    def clean_field2(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data['field2']
        print value 
        return value
```

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP, and the individual field cleaners are not being called either.